# How to store a dictionary into my parse dashboard and extract data from it (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to know how to store the dictionary below into my parse dashboard, store whatever book the user adds on my app and pull the data again whenever the user needs it.

```
let currentUser = PFUser.current()

var bookInShelf: [String: AnyObject] = [

        "book_title" : titleLabel.text as AnyObject,
        "book_author" : authorLabel.text as AnyObject,
        "book_publisher" : publisherLabel.text as AnyObject,
        "book_pages" : numOfPagesLabel.text as AnyObject,
        "book_image" : bookImage.image!
    ]
```

I tested the code `bookInShelf["book_title"] = currentUser?["bookTitle"] as AnyObject` and it shows `[Error]: Invalid field name: bookTitle().`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can do this?

```
> currentUser?["bookTitle"] as AnyObject
```

It seems that you can't access to bookTitle on current user, are you sure you can subscribe to this?

Comment: Yeah, it's actually wrong and that's why I'm getting an error. I don't know the way around it. I need a solution to save the book details i.e. bookTitle into my parse server.